# How to remove a certificate Authority installed on my Android mobile ( redmi note 5)

Tags: android-versions, redmi

I installed an app **LUMEN** that app installed a certificate, ever since it installed that certificate it is showing that *your secure network maybe monitored or modified*

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to:

`Settings > Security > Encryption & Credentials > Trusted Credentials > User`

You can remove the installed CA from there.